# Reducing a scanned pdf file size

Tags: pdf, compression

I need to compress a scanned PDF file from 1.5 MB to under 600 KB. I've tried a number of Ghostscript solutions given on other threads but they seem to compress it all the way down to just 2.2 KB and all the content is lost. Can someone provide a solution?

Answer (score 5):

You may experiment with the `convert input.pdf -resample 85% output.pdf` command example.

Reference: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php#usage

Depending on the quality of the original, the results may not be very good.

Comment: I found this *increased* the size of my PDF by a factor of 14 (with a resample parameter of 50%)

Comment: Unfortunately it happens on certain pdf types.

Comment: This works fine to me with my scanned documents. *e.g.* `convert scan*.jpg -colorspace gray -resample 100% "MyDocs.pdf"`

Comment: whatever I set the resample value to, my resulting PDF is of so low quality (low resolution and/or lossy compression) that I cannot read anything anymore

Answer (score -1):

It would be helpful to see what options you tried with Ghostscript because normally that should work better than ImageMagick.

You can also try pdfjam. To install

```
sudo apt-get install pdfjam
```

Then try variants of these commands

```
pdfjam --scale 0.5 your.pdf
```

or try the `--papersize` flag. Run `pdfjam --help` for a full list of options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the scale option does not reduce the PDF file size. It only adjusts the page margins. In fact, I wasn't able to find any pdfjam option that would actually reduce DPI/image quality and this file size.

Comment: using --scale or ----papersize does not reduce the size of the pdf.

Comment: your "answer" is a comment; you should provide specific solutions using gs; just as in pdfjam.